# "Рост населения"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Порой по телевидению или в газете можно услышать/увидеть выражение "рост населения" или "население сокращается". Но разве так правильно говорить? Разве не численность населения растет или сокращается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, но дело не в "сокращении" понятия на одно слово.
"Рост какого-то показателя" - вполне нормальный оборот. Рост цен, рост заболеваемости и проч. Так что вопрос только в том, можно ли "население" (а не "численность населения") рассматривать как показатель. По некотором размышлении я готов согласиться. К "населению" нет удобного термина, означающего численность  (сравните: заболевание - заболеваемость). Поэтому слово "население" выступает как бы в двух качествах, означая и само население, и его численность. Ничего страшного. Единственная проблема - "рост" путается с показаетелем его, населения, физического роста, т.е. высоты в стоячем положении. Но уж это как-нибудь переживем.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, правильно "рост численности населения", однако в речевой практике слово "численности" зачастую сокращается. Фраза без "численности" понятна русскому человеку,а вот иностранцу ее понять трудно, как и многие другие фразы.

Answer (score 0):

Если не очень нравится фраза *рост населения*, можно использовать *прирост населения*. Хотя можно и так, и этак.